# how to reload script after autopost back in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I have used search dropdownlist with javascript . if the page postback automatically the search dropdownlist become ordinary dropdownlist

```
<link href="Styles/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
<script src="Scripts/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_patientname" runat="server" class="chzn-select dropdown" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_patientname_SelectedIndexChanged1">
</asp:DropDownList>

<script>
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
    $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
</script>
```

Comment: It seems that the code you provided is not complete as it is in your asp.net file. 
Please also share some c# code

Comment: Is there any clue in console log? Could you please check it after post back by pressing `ctrl + shift + j`?

Comment: Please confirm css and javascript file references are in the head section of your file ?
And use document.ready call just before end of body tag and call the chosen script in the document.ready. For example: 
$(document).ready(function () {  
$(".chzn-select").chosen();  
      $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });  });

Comment: @KhurramIshaque we have placed it in header section rightly  and palaced it inside the body tag . we use a search dropdown list with autopostback true. still it disappears and becomes ordinary dropdownlist

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz console error -Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Are you using update panels? Please show some more html of your page.

Comment: yes ,@KhurramIshaque .<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> <ContentTemplate>
  <div class="main_div">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_patientname" runat="server" class="chzn-select dropdown" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_patientname_SelectedIndexChanged1" Visible="False">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
         </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take DropDownList outside the updated panel, if you can.
You can include trigger for dropdownlist in update panel like:

```
<Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_patientname" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
```

If not, you can use like the following code:

```
function populateChosonDdl()
{
   $(".chzn-select").chosen(); 
   $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
}
$(document).ready(function () { 
    populateChosonDdl();
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
if (prm) {
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        populateChosonDdl();
    });
}
```

This should keep the customization on dropdownlist intact.